# Is there a word for “that’s not my fault”?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

Is there a word for “that’s not my fault”?

Sometimes it’s easy to be associated with something negative, but it is not your fault but the wrongly association. Would the word *innocent* describe it correctly?

Let me give a more vivid example for better understanding. Suppose you were walking down the sidewalk, and all of the sudden, the car besides you started to sound the alarm sound. Out rushed a big fellow, and since you are the only one around the car, he shouted at you “what have you done to my car?”. This is a fake example (what’s the better word for *fake* here?), but illustrates my point very well.

I’m thinking *“I’m innocent”* does not quite describe the situation, does it? And not even *“that’s not my fault”*; *“It has nothing to do with me”* would be more appropriate. Is there any words or phrases that is suitable for such situation?

Comment: I’m not sure you’ll find anything shorter than “(it) wasn’t me[.](http://youtu.be/pslgz9o8meM)” As for your parenthetical question, you could say “this is (a) fiction(al example)”.

Comment: [The gesture of showing both palms raised near the shoulders](http://s.pikabu.ru/images/big_size_comm/2013-12_2/13865463126881.jpg) could accompany this declaration of innocence, or even stand in its place.

Comment: @Tyler - Spot on. As a matter of fact, earlier this year, I was leaving a crowded stadium after a sporting event. There was a couple in front of us; he gave her a quick caress, and I overheard her say, "Somebody's touching my butt; it had better be you." As they turned around, I made that exact gesture, and said, "Wasn't me." We all had a good laugh over it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I'm innocent" seems to imply that you are involved, but it works well.
As for "culpable", which was given in a different answer, it is a bit unused in normal conversation, and may not be understood by some people.
Personally, I would either say "I didn't do it" or "I'm innocent".

Comment: I think the fact that a word is slightly unused in normal conversation and that it may not be understood by some people is all the more reason to use the word!! I try to encourage broader vocabularies whenever I can ;)

Answer (score 4):

Since you asked for a word, I'll give you a word: ***culpable***. [CDO](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/culpable) defines it as:

> **culpable** (*adjective*) `formal` deserving to be blamed or considered responsible for something bad

A synonym would be *blameworthy*.

I'll admit, though: I like how the dictionary labels that word as `formal`. Even though the word means exactly what you want it to mean, it's probably not a word I'd use in your *contrived* scenario. As others have said, I would probably say something more along the lines of:

> I didn't do anything!
>   It wasn't my fault!

or even:

> I swear, it was just a coincidence.

The word *culpable* is usually reserved for more formal contexts like this one:

> Just because she was physically absent when the murders took place did not mean that she was not culpable. (Ken Englade, *Beyond Reason*, 2011)

Comment: Err... "*I'm not blameworthy.*"? Why not simply say "*I'm blameless.*"?

Comment: @Pace - Sure, you could say that. Personally, I'd prefer, _"I'm not to blame"_ over either of those options. (_"I'm not to blame"_ seems to apply more to the situation at hand, while _"I'm blameless"_ seems to connote some long-term measure of infallibility.) That said, _blameless_ could still be used quite effectively, if the wording is right. For instance, I like this example dictionary sentence: _It was ​mainly my ​fault, but she wasn't ​entirely blameless_ (CDO).

Answer (score 3):

How about: "blameless"?

It is a slightly stronger statement.

(I originally submitted the first sentence along, but the answer was rejected for not being at least 30 characters - what is the bias against brevity here?)

Comment: It's not a bias against brevity, it's a bias toward fleshing out answers by providing supporting evidence, such as sample usages from literature, or dictionary definitions that confirm the word you are suggesting is indeed a good fit.

Answer (score 2):

I'd answer, "Not me!"  It's technically incorrect grammar, as WendiKidd noted, but it's absolutely idiomatic and will be understood unambiguously.

*This is a fake example (what’s the better word for fake here?)*

Constructed.  Invented.  Hypothetical.

You could also replace "example" with "scenario", e.g. "This is an invented scenario."

Answer (score -1):

True, *innocent* binds you with its limitations though you are innocent in that case. Let me tell you my opinion.

**This can be said in a various ways and there's no one word/phrase for that.** Depending upon the situation, you can put yourself as *an innocent* because you did nothing. Some examples:

> *(Hey,) I did nothing!* 
>   *It's not me!* 
>   *It wasn't me!* (Credit -Tyler) 
>   *I didn't do it!* And so on...

As far as *fake* is concerned, you probably mean to say *fictional* or *let me surmise a scene for you.*

Comment: "It's not me" isn't correct here. I'm not sure exactly how to explain why, but it isn't right. "I did nothing" is correct, but I think more often you'd hear "I didn't do anything!" which of course means the same thing :)

Comment: @WendiKidd You can doubt any suggestion like that because ultimately, there are many ways to express this. In fact, out of all, I vote *It's not me!* as this is the typical expressions we get especially in cases like - **Your friend pokes you and hides behind me.** You look at me angrily. I'd immediately say *Hey, it's not me!* There, *I din' do anything* does not make that good sense.

Comment: I'm just telling you it's not standard English. In the case you described, "It wasn't me!" would be appropriate. "It's not me" doesn't make any sense (*what* isn't you?). "I didn't do anything" also works.

Comment: Thanks everyone. All answers are good answers. Up voting for everyone!...